# Create .desktop file for Kdenlive appimage

Tags: launcher

I decided to use the appimage version of Kdenlive and decided to create a `kdenlive.desktop` and placed it in `~/.local/share/applications` file that launches the appimage. The contents is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=/home/username/Apps/Kdenlive/kdenlive-logo-hori.png
Name[en_US]=Kdenlive (AppImage)
Exec=/home/username/Apps/Kdenlive/kdenlive-19.12.3-x86_64.AppImage
Name=Kdenlive (AppImage)
Icon=/home/username/Apps/Kdenlive/kdenlive-logo-hori.png
Categories=Application;Video;
GenericName=Kdenlive (AppImage)
Comment=Video Editor
```

I made the file executable, but the launcher is not appearing in overview. This is not the first time I created such files and they usually work. What is wrong with this file?
I can launch the Appimage by double-clicking the file in Nautilus.

Comment: I don't think a shebang makes sense in a .desktop-file.

Comment: Removing the first line doesn't make a difference, however. App still doesn't show in Overview.

Comment: Are you sure the spelling of the file-name is correct? When I download the AppImage from https://files.kde.org/kdenlive/release/ I have `kdenlive-19.12.3-x86_64.appimage`, not `kdenlive-19.12.3-x86_64.AppImage`.

Comment: Post that as an answer and I'll recognise it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the filename from https://files.kde.org/kdenlive/release/ led us to a misspelled path to the appimage in the `.desktop`-file.

The downloaded file is `kdenlive-19.12.3-x86_64.appimage`, not `kdenlive-19.12.3-x86_64.AppImage`.