# Running an application with specific file extension using .desktop file

Tags: launcher, .desktop, customization

I want to run an appimage available in a particular directory irrespective of its name. I tried this way without success,

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=application
Icon=application.png
Path=/path/to/application/
Exec=/path/to/application/*.AppImage
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=application
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-BAMFGenerated=true
```

How can I run an application with specific file extension using .desktop file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create .desktop file for Kdenlive appimage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224421/create-desktop-file-for-kdenlive-appimage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use wildcards in a `.desktop` file. You need to be specific in what you want to run and provide at least the name of the AppImage file if it resides in a folder that is included in your search path, or the full pathname if it does not.

Perhaps you are asking this question because you do not want to change the `.desktop` each time you upgrade the AppImage. In that case, there are some possibilities:

- Rename your `.AppImage` so it has a generic name, e.g. `Shotcut-200628.glibc2.14-x86_64.AppImage` ->  `shotcut`, so you can reference the appimage as `<path>/shotcut` in your `.desktop`file. Drawback: you do not readily see anymore which version you have from the file name.

Alternatively:

- Create a symlink to the `.AppImage` file in a folder that is in your search path, e.g. `~/bin/shotcut` -> `<path>/Shotcut-200628.glibc2.14-x86_64.AppImage`, then refer to the symbolic link in your desktop file.

Advantages:

- You keep the AppImage name, thus immediately can see the version.
- In the `.desktop` file, it is sufficient to provide the name of the executable, `shotcut`, because that is in your search path.
- You can also launch the AppImage from the terminal or the run dialog <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> with the command `shotcut`.

Drawback:

- When updating the appimage, you need to update the symbolic link.

Answer (score 5):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=sh -c "/home/theWu/Downloads/*.AppImage"
Name=colontracee
Icon=/home/theWu/Pictures/tracee1.jpg
Categories=Application
```

...worked for me, the way the OP requested... But if I was doing this I would be concerned if there was multiple .AppImage in the directory. It grabbed the first one based on alphabetical order.

.... but the wildcard does work.